# Proving by induction that $(5^{2n})-1$ is divisible by $8$ and $3$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that for all integers *n* that $5^{2n}-1$ is divisible by $8$ and $3$. Explain

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860019/proof-by-induction-for-any-integer-n-0-352n-%E2%88%92-1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by Induction: For any integer $n \gt 0$,  $3|(5^{2n} − 1)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860019/proof-by-induction-for-any-integer-n-0-352n-%e2%88%92-1)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Oh and by the way, Welcome to MSE! could you please take some time to read [ask] a good question? This avoids your (future) questions being heavily downvoted or closed

Comment: $25\equiv1\bmod24, $ so $5^{2n}-1=25^n-1\equiv0\bmod24, $ so $\bmod 8$ and $3$

Comment: @Aryadeva I let n=k+1 and got (25)(5^2k)-1

Comment: @sai-kartik Okay, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

$5^{2(n+1)}-1=25\times5^{2n}-1=25\times5^{2n}-25+24=25\times(5^{2n}-1)+24$

And so we can see that *if* $5^{2n}-1$ is divisible by 3 and 8, *then* $5^{2(n+1)}-1$ is ... ?

Comment: How do you get the -25+24?

Comment: Add 24 to the previous expression and also subtract it.  What do you get?